# Tcl string range behavior

Tags: tcl

A small routine places a five character marker within an output file every several thousand bytes, that marker containing numbers that usually are > 10000, but may contain as few as one digit. The marker must contain five characters, and are thus left side padded with zeros. Since the length of the marker is unknown at the beginning of each iteration, four zeroes are padded and then some or all are dropped.

Assume that x represents the actual marker and that x = 400

If I:

```
set x 0000$x
set x [string range $x [expr [string length $x] - 5] end]
```

the script will return "00400", which is what we need. However, if I shorten it to:

```
set x [string range $x [expr [string length "0000$x"] - 5] end]
```

it will return "0". I hope someone can point out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `set x [format “%05d” $x]` looks like the easiest way to do this.  (Your second attempt failed because you never actually added any leading zeros to the string.)

Comment: that worked, thank you, I'm still not quite sure why the second example won't add the leading zeros when something like ```set x [string range $x [expr [string length "0000400"] - 5] end]``` will work fine

Comment: While `format` is the better way to do what you want, you can make your method work by doing `set x [string range [set x "0000$x"] [expr {[string length $x] - 5}] end]`.

Comment: The format method seems much more efficient, and so that's how I'm leaving it, but as a non-programmer who just makes these little scripts as needed, I wanted to know why, for future reference, how things work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, you are computing the length of one string (`0000400`) and then taking the characters from another (`400`).

```
% string length 0000400
7
% string range 400 2 end
0
```

You'd be better to use `format` or end-relative indexing:

```
string range "0000$x" end-4 end
```

```
format "%05d" $x
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the expression `[string length "0000$x"]`, it calculates the length of the string `"0000$x"`, i.e. 4 + total characters in `$x`. But when you select `string range $x` (length of x only) this is where the error arises. You have to use `"0000$x"` in both the places, but you are using it at one place only.

```
set x [string range "0000$x" [expr [string length "0000$x"] - 5] end]
```

This ensures that the length is calculated for the entire string `"0000$x"` and then extracts the desired substring.
Also you can use

```
set x [string range 0000$x [expr [string length 0000$x] - 5] end]
```

They both yield the same results.
But if you are working with just number then using `format` is more feasible.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "it calculates the length of the string "0000$x" including the dollar sign" -- no, the variable will be expanded thanks to the double quotes.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. In Tcl, `"0000$x"` becomes the concatenation of the literal string `0000` and the contents of the variable called `x`. That's literally what it means and the meaning has never changed since the very first days of the language.

Comment: I also meant the same, that if using "0000$x", the string length that is calculated will be 4 (as we have four zeros) + number of characters in the variable x (lets say x=400, so there are three characters/elements). So for this case the sting length will be 7.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, capture the last 5 characters with a regular expression:

```
set marker [regexp -inline {.{5}$} "0000$x"]
```